# Shiny - Render multiple outputs in parallel

Tags: r, parallel-processing, shiny, future, shiny-reactivity

When I want to render multiple outputs linked to a single observer, they are rendered after both outputs are calculated. If there is a long calculation between the outputs it takes a long time before all outputs are displayed.

Is it possible in a Shiny application to render outputs, linked to a single observer, individually or in parallel? Instead of waiting with rendering until all outputs are calculated.

**Example**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('button', 'klik'),
  textOutput('first'),
  textOutput('second')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent({input$button},{
    output$first <- renderText({Sys.Date()})
    Sys.sleep(10)
    output$second <- renderText({Sys.Date()})
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I would be against doing anything heavy inside the `observeEvent`, including rendering UIs, have a look at the modules https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Comment: look into this article https://www.r-bloggers.com/long-running-tasks-with-shiny-challenges-and-solutions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @BertilBaron I found out a way to avoid waiting for long calculations in `R-Shiny`. The article that I used can be found [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/long-running-tasks-with-shiny-challenges-and-solutions/).

Basically what you do is to run each process in parallel using the package `future`. With this package every time the user clicks on the button the calculation will be performed. So keep in mind that you have to build in a block for impatient users.

**My working example**

```
library(shiny)
library(promises)
library(future)
plan(multiprocess)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton('button', 'klik'),
  textOutput('first'),
  textOutput('second')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  nclicks <- reactiveVal(0)
  nclicks2 <- reactiveVal(0)
  result_val <- reactiveVal()
  result_val2 <- reactiveVal()

  observeEvent(input$button,{
    # Don't do anything if analysis is already being run
    if(nclicks() != 0 | nclicks2() != 0){
      showNotification("Already running analysis")
      return(NULL)
    }

    # Increment clicks and prevent concurrent analyses
    nclicks(nclicks() + 1)
    nclicks2(nclicks2() + 1)

    result <- future({
      # Long Running Task
      Sys.sleep(10)

      #Some results
      Sys.time()
    }) %...>% result_val()

    result2 <- future({
      #Some results
      Sys.time()
    }) %...>% result_val2()

    # Catch inturrupt (or any other error) and notify user
    result <- catch(result,
                    function(e){
                      result_val(NULL)
                      print(e$message)
                      showNotification(e$message)
                    })
    result2 <- catch(result2,
                    function(e){
                      result_val2(NULL)
                      print(e$message)
                      showNotification(e$message)
                    })

    # After the promise has been evaluated set nclicks to 0 to allow for anlother Run
    result <- finally(result,
                      function(){
                        nclicks(0)
                      })
    result2 <- finally(result2,
                      function(){
                        nclicks2(0)
                      })

    # Return something other than the promise so shiny remains responsive
    NULL
  })

  output$first <- renderText({
    req(result_val())
  })
  output$second <- renderText({
    req(result_val2())
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```